# strange text sent from my phone to a friend

Tags: mobile

A friend received a text from my phone which actually used my husbands name in the text. It was not from me and does not show up in my text message thread. The text does not include a link or any picture.

I also received from a friend a strange text that I know she would not have sent. It was sent in the middle of the night and about Valentine's day card. Again no link or picture.

What is going on?

Comment: I don't know of any ongoing big attack or similar but this sounds like sms spoofing.
Where somebody fakes the sender of the sms just like with e-mails. This could have been a try to perform social engineering and gather more informations? This is a pure assumption on the last part.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like both of the SMS messages that you described were 'spoofed' to make them look like they were sent from a phone number other than the actual phone number that they were sent from.  It's not difficult to do, and it's not uncommon.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS_spoofing for more info.

Comment: Is it anything I need to worry about or do something about?

Comment: If you're sure that the message is fake, then I think you can just delete it.